# Find Index of Zero or Almost Zero Rows

Tags: matlab

I have a NxM matrix with mixed rows

```
A = [[1.1 2.2 3.0]; [0.00000009 0 0]; [0 0 0]; [1 2 3]];
```

I want to find indices of all zero rows in A. From [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39992-indices-of-all-non-zeros-rows) I've tried

```
find(all(A==0,2))
```

and I am able to get the index of 3rd row i.e. [0 0 0] but not 2nd row which is also almost zero. How can i find all such rows which are either all zero or almost very near to zero.

I've used the following as work around but I don't think so its the correct way to solve this problem.

```
idx = unique([find(all(A<0.000001,2));find(all(A==0,2))]);
```

What is the correct way? Thanks for any help

Comment: Try and use the *round* function. This will allow you to round to the significant digit of interest. Then repeat the find function.

Comment: Your approach is just fine assuming positive numbers, but can be simplified to `idx = find(all(A<0.000001,2))`. Note that almost zero is not well defined. So, you need to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define what you count as "almost very near to zero":

```
inc=1E-5;
```

Then, match the search to that criteria:

```
idx=find(all(abs(A)<inc,2))
```

The result is:

```
idx =

     2
     3
```